# script for offsite links in new window, does not collect all links from page

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm total beginner and this is my first question.

I recently setup a site and have some external links to it. All are set to open in same window by default, but wanted to give visitors choice to toggle external links to open in new window.

I found great script from: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/newwindow2.htm

**edit**
Here is the script from dynamicdrive:

```
//Open offsite links in new window script- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/
//Created: August 28th, 2007'

var ddwindowlinks={
//1)Enter domains to be EXCLUDED from opening in new window:
excludedomains: ["dynamicdrive.com", "google.com"],

//2) Target for links that should open in a new window (ie: "_blank", "secwin" etc):
linktarget: "_blank",

//3) Specify operating mode ("auto" or "manual"):
mode: "manual",

//4) If mode is "manual", customize checkbox HTML to show to users (Preserve id attribute):
toggleHTML: '<form><input type="checkbox" id="targetcheckbox" checked="checked" /><label for="targetcheckbox">Open off-site links in new window?</label></form>',

//5) If mode is "manual", enable user persistence so the state of the checkbox is remembered?
persist: true,

assigntarget:function(){
    var rexcludedomains=new RegExp(this.excludedomains.join("|"), "i")
    var all_links=document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    if (this.mode=="auto" || (this.mode=="manual" && this.togglebox.checked)){
        for (var i=0; i<=(all_links.length-1); i++){
            if (all_links[i].hostname.search(rexcludedomains)==-1 && all_links[i].href.indexOf("http:")!=-1)
                all_links[i].target=ddwindowlinks.linktarget
        }
    }
    else{
        for (var i=0; i<=(all_links.length-1); i++)
            all_links[i].target=""
    }
    if (this.mode=="manual" && this.persist)
        this.setCookie("dlinktarget", (this.togglebox.checked)? "yes" : "no", 30) //remember user setting for 30 days (set to -1 then reload page to erase cookie)
},

init:function(){
    if (document.getElementById && this.mode=="manual"){
        document.write(this.toggleHTML)
        this.togglebox=document.getElementById("targetcheckbox")
        this.togglebox.onclick=function(){ddwindowlinks.assigntarget()}
        if (this.persist && this.getCookie("dlinktarget")!="")
            this.togglebox.checked=(this.getCookie("dlinktarget")=="yes")? true : false
    }
    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", function(){ddwindowlinks.assigntarget()}, false)
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", function(){ddwindowlinks.assigntarget()})
},

getCookie:function(Name){
    var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]+", "i"); //construct RE to search for target name/value pair
    if (document.cookie.match(re)) //if cookie found
        return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] //return its value
    return ""
},

setCookie:function(name, value, days){
    var expireDate = new Date()
    //set "expstring" to either an explicit date (past or future)
        var expstring=expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+parseInt(days))
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()+"; path=/"
}

}

ddwindowlinks.init()
```

**end edit**

The script works excelent for links that are on text.

**Example**

```
<div class="Artistic-Body-P">
    <span class="Artistic-Body-C">
        <a href="http://externallink.com" style="text-decoration:none;">test</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

but it's not working for links that are within div rollover.
example:

```
<div id="div_popup_roll_13" style="position:absolute;left:109px;top:259px;width:76px;height:76px;">
    <a href="http://externallink.com" rev="image1.png~#~-14~#~-15~#~text~#~148~#~-119~#~#949393~#~Tahoma~#~30~#~0~#~1~#~transparent~#~165">
        <img src="image2.png" border="0" width="76" height="76" id="popup_roll_13" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

I have been busting my head for two days how to fix this, but guess that the fact that I'm beginner, doesn't help so I decided to post here.

thnx for help in advance

**edit**

here is the code from poproll:

```
(function($){jQuery.fn.poproll=function(settings){var m_bHovering=false;var m_nDivId=0;
var $m_ImageDiv=null;var $m_TextDiv=null;
var eOptions={Img:0,ImgPosX:1,ImgPosY:2,Txt:3,TxtPosX:4,TxtPosY:5,TxtCol:6,TxtFont:7,TxtSize:8,TxtItallic:9,TxtBold:10,TxtBkgrndCol:11,TxtWidth:12};
function ClosePopup(){if($m_ImageDiv!==null){$m_ImageDiv.remove();
$m_ImageDiv=null;if($m_TextDiv!==null){$m_TextDiv.remove();
$m_TextDiv=null}}}function HoverOver(div){m_bHovering=true;var nDivId=$(div).attr('id');
if(nDivId!==m_nDivId){m_nDivId=nDivId;ClosePopup()}if($m_ImageDiv===null){var anchor=$(div).find('a');
var optionArray=$(anchor).attr('rev').split('~#~');
var href=$(anchor).attr('href');
if(href===undefined){$(div).append('<div id="poproll_img" style="position:absolute; left:'+optionArray[eOptions.ImgPosX]+'px; top:'+optionArray[eOptions.ImgPosY]+'px; z-index:100;"><img src="'+optionArray[eOptions.Img]+'" name="popup_roll_2" alt="" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;"></div>')}else{$(div).append('<div id="poproll_img" style="position:absolute; left:'+optionArray[eOptions.ImgPosX]+'px; top:'+optionArray[eOptions.ImgPosY]+'px; z-index:100;"><a href='+href+'><img src="'+optionArray[eOptions.Img]+'" name="popup_roll_2" alt="" border="0" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;"></a></div>')}$m_ImageDiv=$('#poproll_img');
if(optionArray[eOptions.Txt].length>0){var fontStyle=optionArray[eOptions.TxtItallic]>0?'italic':'normal';
var fontWeight=optionArray[eOptions.TxtBold]>0?'bold':'normal';$(div).append('<div id="poproll_txt" style="position:absolute; left:'+optionArray[eOptions.TxtPosX]+'px; top:'+optionArray[eOptions.TxtPosY]+'px; width:'+optionArray[eOptions.TxtWidth]+'px; color:'+optionArray[eOptions.TxtCol]+'; font-size:'+optionArray[eOptions.TxtSize]+'; font-family:'+optionArray[eOptions.TxtFont]+'; font-style: '+fontStyle+'; font-weight:'+fontWeight+'; background-color:'+optionArray[eOptions.TxtBkgrndCol]+'; z-index:100;">'+optionArray[eOptions.Txt]+'</div>');$m_TextDiv=$('#poproll_txt')}}}function HoverOut(){m_bHovering=false;window.setTimeout(function(){if(!m_bHovering){ClosePopup()}},100)}this.hover(function(){HoverOver(this)},function(){HoverOut()})}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I just saw your comment sorry. I re-edited the original post and included original scrip, although the script that was suggested by Graham Robertson works the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

It might just be cleaner to write the code yourself.  Try the following:

```
// Grab every <a> tag in the document.
var allTheTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

function parseTags(tags) {
    var size = tags.length; // cache the size;

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var tag = tags[i];
        var href = tag.getAttribute('href');
        // Do we have a target attribute? (and, of course, an href attribute)
        if (href && !tag.getAttribute('target')) {
              var ourHostName = window.location.hostname;
              href = href.split('://');
              // Is there a protocol?
              if (href.length > 1) {
                  href = href[1].split('/')[0]; // Get everything before the first /
                  if (href != window.location.hostname &&
                      href != 'www' + window.location.hostname) {
                      // Sometimes, hostname does not have www in it.
                      tag.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                  }
              }
        }
    }
};

// Call our function.
parseTags(allTheTags);
```

Our variable "allTheTags" is a Nodelist, which will update when the DOM updates, so we can always re-run our parseTags function passing in our allTheTags object each time.  This way, we skip querying the DOM if there's an instance where a tags are added dynamically.

**EDIT**

In the case of accounting for poproll functionality, you'll have to listen for the same roll-over event you pass to your poproll function.  So, right after you call poproll on the element you selected, listen for a hover on that same element.

```
$(someElementYouUseForPoproll).hover(function () {
    parseTags(allTheTags);
}, function() { });
```

This way, after our markup has been injected, this hover event is next in-line to be executed and will now see the  tag the poproll generated in the DOM.

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks a tone for quick answer, I just tried the js you suggested, unfortunately the problem persists. Still working ok on text links and not working on rollovers. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: hmmmm this should definitely work.  Is the markup for the pop-up being generated by JavaScript and added to the DOM later?

Comment: I think so. There is jquery js for the poproll also, do you want me to paste the code from it?

Comment: Most definitely.  As I stated in my answer above though, if you can listen to the event which renders the pop-up, you can run the parseTags function again as the a tag in that div will now be part of the DOM.

Comment: Thnx again m8, I'm apologizing for being a noob, but the edit you made do I insert at the end of the script you suggested, and the "someElementYouUseForPoproll" do I change this with the name of jquery that I use for rollovers? Once again thnx and sorry for my noobness.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, by editing the code for the poprol, changed the href to:

```
<a href="'+href+'" target="_blank">
```